# Loss not decreasing with Longformer and Custom Classification Head

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification

I am trying to use Longformer to build a classification model for a task with 9 classes. I am downloading the model from Huggingface and putting my own Tensorflow head on top. However, the loss is not decreasing past a certain point. I have tried Huggingfaces DistilBert for sequence classification on the same corpus and it works just fine. Interestingly though, when I use DistilBert with my custom head, it only works after exchanging Keras' Adam optimizer with one with a decaying learning rate. When I try that with the Longformer nothing changes though. Anyone know what's going on here? Btw. running all this on Colab GPU.

The data:

```
# tokenize training data
tokens = tokenizer(list(train_dataset['description'].values), 
                               padding="max_length",
                               truncation=True)

train_tokens = tokens['input_ids']
train_attention = tokens['attention_mask']
train_targets = train_dataset['labels'].values
train_targets = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_targets)
```

The model: model_name = "allenai/longformer-base-4096"

```
def build_model(num_classes):

tokens = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,), name = 'tokens', dtype=tf.int32)
attention = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,), name = 'attention', dtype=tf.int32)

config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_name)
backbone = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name, config=config)

#for w in backbone.longformer.weights:
 # w._trainable= False

x = backbone(tokens, attention_mask=attention)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x.pooler_output)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', dtype='float32')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[tokens,attention], outputs=x)
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss = [tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()],
              metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])

return model
```

Model training:

```
with strategy.scope():
    model = build_model(9)

    model.fit(x = [train_tokens, train_attention],
              y = train_targets,
              validation_data = ([val_tokens, val_attention], val_targets),
              epochs = 3,
              batch_size = 1,
              verbose = 1)

Output:
Epoch 1/3
12150/12150 [==============================] - 5906s 486ms/step - loss: 2.1984 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1032 - val_loss: 2.1973 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1111
Epoch 2/3
12150/12150 [==============================] - 5893s 485ms/step - loss: 2.1982 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1119 - val_loss: 2.1975 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1111
Epoch 3/3
12150/12150 [==============================] - 5892s 485ms/step - loss: 2.1981 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1068 - val_loss: 2.1975 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1111
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fb2ff62a4d0>
```

Model Summary:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 tokens (InputLayer)            [(None, 4096)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 attention (InputLayer)         [(None, 4096)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 tf_longformer_model (TFLongfor  TFLongformerBaseMod  148659456  ['tokens[0][0]',                 
 merModel)                      elOutputWithPooling               'attention[0][0]']              
                                (last_hidden_state=                                               
                                (None, 4096, 768),                                                
                                 pooler_output=(Non                                               
                                e, 768),                                                          
                                 hidden_states=None                                               
                                , attentions=None,                                                
                                global_attentions=N                                               
                                one)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 32)           24608       ['tf_longformer_model[0][1]']    
                                                                                                  
 dense_1 (Dense)                (None, 9)            297         ['dense[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 148,684,361
Trainable params: 148,684,361
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Can you show the model summary?

Comment: @DPM I added the summary. Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: How many epochs have you ran the model for? Only 3, or more?

Comment: @DPM I also ran it for 10 epochs, but the loss did not change. I had the same implementation with a CNN-Head where changing the learning rate of the optimizer did the trick. But I can't figure out how to set the optimizer to make it work with the dense layer head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with a tiny learning rate (1.25e-06) and the introduction of warm up steps to the optimizer!